# Check if a moment date is before or after another moment date

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

My check below doesn't seem to work for checking if a moment date is before or after a moment date given. It seems to be adding another day. So instead of the condition being true on Friday 3/30, which is today plus 3 more days, it's only true for Saturday March 31 and after.

Here is what I'm doing. 'scope.calendarDateSelected' is a moment date returned from fullcalendar.js

```js
if (scope.calendarDateSelected <= moment().add(3, 'days')) {
  // should be less then 3 days
} else {
  // after 3 days out
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure the timezones of the two dates match?

Comment: pretty sure they do, I just ran it in the immediate window and they both show Pacific Daylight Time

Comment: If I reduce the numberOfDays by 1, so that it adds 2 days, then it seems to work. So it returns a true for Friday 30

Comment: What hour and minute is `scope.calendarDateSelected`?

Comment: Are you setting the time to 00:00:00.0?

Comment: From the docs "Currently the following browsers are used for the ci system: Chrome on Windows XP, IE 8, 9, and 10 on Windows 7, IE 11 on Windows 10, latest Firefox on Linux, and latest Safari on OSX 10.8 and 10.11". So, Chrome/Linux is not listed, beware of that.

Comment: Use [query](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) functions like [`isSameOrBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/) to compare moment objects instead of `<=`